# append data from handlebars value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, templating

i'm using emberjs with handlebars and i have an issue.

The idea is append a value into the element, the result will show something like that:

```
<li data-obj="CASH_IN_BANK">CASH_IN_BANK</li>
```

i'm trying that:

```
<li data-obj="{{row.value}}">{{row.value}}</li>
```

but is not working the result out the taks is fine but the data-obj shows the handlebar script tags

```
<li data-obj="<script id='metamorph-9-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>TAG_CASH_IN_BANK<script id='metamorph-9-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>" >
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `{{bind-attr attribute=value}}. See: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/

in your case it would be...

```
<li {{bind-attr data-obj=row.value}}">{{row.value}}</li>
```